# using tab key inside a menu item

Tags: javascript, html

I have a menu control which renders the final output as below.This menu is opened based on a javascript function.Using the tab key I can get to this element and then hit enter and then press the tab key to go inside and then cycle through the options.The issue is that after reaching the end element pressing tab again makes the first option highlighted instead of going to the next element of the page.can someone please guide me about what can i do to achieve this.

```
<menu id="zz4_FeatureMenuTemplate1" largeiconmode="true">
        <ie:menuitem id="zz5_MenuItem_CreateDocLib" menugroupid="200" description="Create a place to store and share documents." text="New Document Library" onmenuclick="if (LaunchCreateHandler('DocLib')) { GoToPage('\u002fview\u002f_layouts/new.aspx?FeatureId={00bfea71-e717-4e80-aa17-d0c71b360101}&amp;ListTemplate=101') }" iconsrc="/_layouts/images/NewDocLibHH.png" type="option"></ie:menuitem>
        <ie:menuitem id="zz6_MenuItem_CreateSite" menugroupid="200" description="Create a site for a team or project." text="New Site" onmenuclick="if (LaunchCreateHandler('Site')) { STSNavigate('\u002fview\u002f_layouts/newsbweb.aspx') }" iconsrc="/_layouts/images/newweb32.png" type="option"></ie:menuitem>
        <ie:menuitem id="zz7_MenuItem_Create" menugroupid="200" description="Create other types of pages, lists, libraries, and sites." text="More Options..." onmenuclick="if (LaunchCreateHandler('All')) { STSNavigate('\u002fview\u002f_layouts/create.aspx') }" type="option"></ie:menuitem>

        <ie:menuitem id="zz8_MenuItem_ViewAllSiteContents" menugroupid="300" description="View all libraries and lists in this site." text="View All Site Content" onmenuclick="STSNavigate2(event,'/view/_layouts/viewlsts.aspx');" iconsrc="/_layouts/images/allcontent32.png" type="option"></ie:menuitem>
        <ie:menuitem id="zz9_MenuItem_SitePermissions" menugroupid="300" description="Give people access to this site." text="Site Permissions" onmenuclick="STSNavigate2(event,'/view/_layouts/user.aspx');" iconsrc="/_layouts/images/Permissions32.png" type="option"></ie:menuitem>
        <ie:menuitem id="zz10_MenuItem_Settings" menugroupid="300" description="Access all settings for this site." text="Site Settings" onmenuclick="STSNavigate2(event,'/view/_layouts/settings.aspx');" iconsrc="/_layouts/images/settingsIcon.png" type="option"></ie:menuitem>
    </menu>
```

Answer (score 0):

Tab is one of the those tricky keys in html that is a pain to work with.

The most problem proof solution that I have used/seen was to retrieve all the `input/a/button` tags from the document. Store them in an array and when the user presses the tab button capture that event and then give focus to the appropriate element in your array.

Here's some rough code:

```
var elements_array = document.getElementsByTagName("*");
for(var i = elements_array.length; i--){
    if( elements_array[i].indexOf("input") < 0 || elements_array[i].indexOf("a") < 0 || elements_array[i].indexOf("button") < 0){
        elements_array[i].pop();
    }
}

function tab_key(e){
    if(e.keyCode == 9){
        var curr_focus = find_current_focus;
        for(var = elements_array.length; i--){
            if(elements_array[i] == curr_focus){
                var new_focus = elements_array[i+1];
                new_focus.focus();
                break;  
            }        
        }
    }
}

function find_current_focus(){
    return document.activeElement;
}
```

The reason to use the function to return the active element instead of just setting the current focus to the next one in the array, is so that tab will continue to work even if your user clicks on a different `input/a/button` then the order they are in on the page.